# Extracting the text inside a docx file

Tags: f#

I am using the below code to read .docx file and it is successfully extracting the text from the file. But the problem here is, it is just extracting the text. For example if my document data is like below

```
I am line 1

I am line 2      I am some other text
```

Then it is returning me like

```
I am line 1I am line 2I am some other text.
```

I just want as it is. How can I do that.  Below is the code I am using now.

```
 open System
 open System.IO
 open System.IO.Packaging
 open System.Xml

 let getDocxContent (path: string) =
 use package = Package.Open(path, FileMode.Open)
 let stream = package.GetPart(new Uri("/word/document.xml",UriKind.Relative)).GetStream()
 stream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore
 let xmlDoc = new XmlDocument()
 xmlDoc.Load(stream)
 xmlDoc.DocumentElement.InnerText
 let docData = getDocxContent @"C:\a1.docx"
 printfn "%s" docData
```

Comment: Do you mean by "as it is" that you want to preserve look and feel?

Comment: for me, it returns; `val docData : string = "I am line 1  I am line 2      I am some other text"` (with the correct number of spaces)

Comment: @GeneBelitski  I dont need formattings but I just need with newlines and spaces to be preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [PreserveWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx) property on your XmlDocument before loading it.

So change the code from:

```
let xmlDoc = new XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.Load(stream)
```

To:

```
let xmlDoc = new XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace <- true
xmlDoc.Load(stream)
```

Comment: Thanks and great help.. How can I preserve newlines as well?

Comment: I don't think you can -- I just created a test document similar to yours then opened the /word/document.xml in a text editor, and there aren't any newlines at all within the document. Instead, the paragraphs are delimited with <w:p>...</w:p> elements -- so you could use an XPath query or LINQ to XML to extract them.

Comment: Thank you much for your help and concerns.. I am wondering what is the use of that many hell of .net libraries..