# VB.Net Search System Directory

Tags: vb.net, search, .net

I am attempting to add a searchbox to my application which will search a shared drive based on the entered criteria. The code I currently have is:

```
Public Sub searchProcedure()

    Dim startFolder As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\Practice Search"

    Dim dir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder)
    Dim fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    Dim searchTerm = "test string"

    Dim queryMatchingFiles = From file In fileList _
                             Let fileText = GetFileText(file.FullName) _
                             Where fileText.Contains(searchTerm) _
                             Select file.FullName

    'Where file.Extension = "." _ (removed so searches all files)

    For Each filename In queryMatchingFiles
        ListBox1.Items.Add(filename)
    Next

End Sub


Function GetFileText(ByRef Name As String) As String

    Dim fileContents = String.Empty

    If System.IO.File.Exists(Name) Then

        fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Name)

    End If

    Return fileContents

End Function
```

The issue I am having is with Microsoft Office documents. The contents are read into my filecontents string, but the contents are in XML (?).

Any ideas on how to pass the actual text content into the string for my search?

Thanks!

Comment: office documents are XML.

Comment: Even as XML, I would still expect to have my text embedded somewhere within the tags, wouldn't I? In which case, the search would be found even with the added XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.docx files are actually ZIP files that contain XML files. Two solutions spring to mind, neither easy:

1. If you have MS Word installed, programmatically open the docx file using the Word object model and extract the text. USing the [MS Office Primary Interop Assembly](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=3508) (PIA) is easier, but limits you to a particular version of Office. I prefer to develop using the PIA then switch to late binding (ie. change everything to "Object" and get rid of the PIA reference) at the end.
2. Use [#ZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) to open the .docx file, and then use the System.Xml namespace to pull the XML apart.

Option 1 I think would be easier for you.

Comment: This might also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485990/extracting-the-text-inside-a-docx-file I've not tried it, but it looks like System.IO.Packaging could be an option

Answer (score 0):

You could stripout the tags entirely when the content is XML or HTML with Regex

```
Regex.Replace(text, "<.*?>", "")
```

like this:

```
Dim fileContents = String.Empty

If System.IO.File.Exists(Name) Then

    fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Name)
    fileContents = Regex.Replace(fileContents, "<.*?>", "")
End If

Return fileContents
```

Comment: I've added the namespace and ran, but to no avail. The real issue appears to be that the XML being passed to fileContents is "jargon".

The document has my name written in it, but this is what is written to filecontents: "PK     ! ���7f      [Content_Types].xml �(�

Comment: To possibly simplify, is there a way to emulate Windows' native search function? When I search a directory with the explorer it will return all results with the keyword in the name and/or file contents, including office documents (I will have to deal with .PDF separately). This is really the behavior I am trying to replicate. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Having come to the conclusion that there is no "out-of-the-box" solution; I am working on each document type. Using the OpenXML SDK, the code to extract from Word is:

```
Imports System.Xml.XmlReader
Imports System.IO
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports System.Linq

Public Sub WordProcessing()


    Dim strDoc As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\Practice.docx"
    Dim txt As String

    Dim stream As Stream = File.Open(strDoc, FileMode.Open)

    OpenAndAddtoWordProcessingStream(stream, txt)

    stream.Close()

    MessageBox.Show(txt)



End Sub

Public Sub OpenAndAddtoWordProcessingStream(ByVal stream As Stream, ByRef txt As String)


    Dim wordprocessingDocument As WordprocessingDocument = wordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, True)

    Dim body As Body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body

    txt = body.InnerText.ToString

    wordprocessingDocument.Close()

End Sub
```

The code to extract from Excel is:

```
  Dim strDoc As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\Practice.xlsx"
    Dim txt As String

    Dim spreadsheetDocument As SpreadsheetDocument = spreadsheetDocument.Open(strDoc, False)

    Dim workbookPart As WorkbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart
    Dim shareStringPart As SharedStringTablePart = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart


    For Each Item As SharedStringItem In shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Elements(Of SharedStringItem)()

        MessageBox.Show(Item.InnerText)

    Next
```

I will look into .PDF, Access and Powerpoint next.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this so the question will be completely answered following SSS's direction. Here is the complete code for searching office docs, office docs(x), pdf, and other generic file formats for text strings.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.XmlReader
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports System.Linq
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation
Imports System.Text
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf

Module searchFiles

Public readAllText As String

Public Sub startSearch(ByVal searchText As String)

    MainForm.marketIntelligencelboxsearch.Items.Clear()

    Dim dir_info As New DirectoryInfo("\\Max1\dept\")

    ListFiles(MainForm.marketIntelligencelboxsearch, dir_info, searchText)

End Sub


Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal lst As ListView, ByVal dir_info As DirectoryInfo, ByVal target As String)
    ' Get the files in this directory.
    Dim fs_infos() As FileInfo = dir_info.GetFiles("*.*")
    For Each fs_info As FileInfo In fs_infos
        If target = "ALL" Or fs_info.ToString().IndexOf(target, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
            MainForm.marketIntelligencelboxsearch.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fs_info.FullName), MainForm.sourceFileImageIndex(fs_info.FullName))
        Else

            readAllText = File.ReadAllText(fs_info.FullName)

            If fileExtention(fs_info.FullName, target) <> 0 Then
                MainForm.marketIntelligencelboxsearch.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fs_info.FullName), MainForm.sourceFileImageIndex(fs_info.FullName))
            End If
        End If
    Next fs_info
    fs_infos = Nothing

    ' Search subdirectories.
    Dim subdirs() As DirectoryInfo = dir_info.GetDirectories()
    For Each subdir As DirectoryInfo In subdirs
        ListFiles(lst, subdir, target)
    Next subdir
End Sub


Public Function fileExtention(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal target As String) As Integer

    Dim searchResult As Integer

    Select Case True

        Case InStr(sourcePath, ".docx") <> 0 Or InStr(sourcePath, ".docm")
            searchResult = WordProcessing(sourcePath, target)
            Return searchResult

        Case InStr(LCase(sourcePath), ".xlsx") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(sourcePath), ".xlsm") <> 0
            searchResult = ExcelProcessing(sourcePath, target)
            Return searchResult

        Case InStr(LCase(sourcePath), ".pptx") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(sourcePath), ".pptm") <> 0
            'will read slide text and notes
            searchResult = PowerpointProcessing(sourcePath, target)
            Return searchResult

        Case InStr(LCase(sourcePath), ".pdf") <> 0
            'will search text in pdf
            searchResult = pdfProcesssing(sourcePath, target)
            Return searchResult

        Case Else
            'looks at office docs before 2007 and all other generic  extensions, includes Access 2007 and lower
            searchResult = catchallProcessing(readAllText, target)
            Return searchResult
    End Select


End Function
```

## Region "Indexof Searching"

```
Public Function catchallProcessing(ByVal strDoc As String, ByVal target As String) As Integer

    If Not (strDoc) Is Nothing Then
        If strDoc.IndexOf(target, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then 'means it ignores the case, no indexof = searching inside
            Return 1

        Else

            Return 0

        End If
    Else

        Return 0
    End If

End Function
```

## End Region

## Region "Word 2007 Processing"

```
Public Function WordProcessing(ByVal strDoc As String, ByVal target As String) As Integer  ' Word 2007 and Higher

    Dim txt As String

    Dim stream As Stream = File.Open(strDoc, FileMode.Open)

    Dim wordprocessingDocument As WordprocessingDocument = wordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, True)

    Dim body As Body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body

    txt = body.InnerText.ToString
    Return catchallProcessing(txt, target) 'should return 0 or 1

    wordprocessingDocument.Close()
    stream.Close()

End Function
```

## End Region

## Region "Excel 2007 Processing"

```
Public Function ExcelProcessing(ByVal strDoc As String, ByVal target As String) As Integer 'Excel 2007 and Higher

    Dim spreadsheetDocument As SpreadsheetDocument = spreadsheetDocument.Open(strDoc, False)

    Dim workbookPart As WorkbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart
    Dim shareStringPart As SharedStringTablePart = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart

    Dim paragraphText As New StringBuilder()

    For Each Item As SharedStringItem In shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Elements(Of SharedStringItem)()

        paragraphText.Append(Item.InnerText) 'should read all strings

    Next

    Return catchallProcessing(paragraphText.ToString(), target)

End Function
```

## End Region

## Region "Powerpoint 2007 Processing"

```
Public Function PowerpointProcessing(ByVal file As String, ByVal target As String) As Integer

    Dim numberOfSlides As Integer = CountSlides(file)

    Dim slideText As String = Nothing
    Dim totalText As String = Nothing

    For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfSlides - 1
        GetSlideIdandText(slideText, file, i)
        totalText = totalText & slideText
        'System.Console.WriteLine("Slide #{0} contains: {1}", i + 1, slideText)
    Next

    Return catchallProcessing(totalText, target)

End Function

Public Function CountSlides(ByVal presentationFile As String) As Integer

    Using powerpointDocument As PresentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(presentationFile, False)

        Return CountSlides(powerpointDocument)

    End Using


End Function

Public Function CountSlides(ByVal powerpointDocument As PresentationDocument) As Integer


    If powerpointDocument Is Nothing Then

        Throw New ArgumentNullException("presentationDocument")

    End If

    Dim slidesCount As Integer = 0

    Dim presentationPart As PresentationPart = powerpointDocument.PresentationPart

    If presentationPart IsNot Nothing Then

        slidesCount = presentationPart.SlideParts.Count()

    End If

    Return slidesCount

End Function

Public Function GetSlideIdandText(ByRef sldText As String, ByVal docName As String, ByVal index As Integer)


    Using ppt As PresentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(docName, False)

        Dim part As PresentationPart = ppt.PresentationPart
        Dim slideIDs As OpenXmlElementList = part.Presentation.SlideIdList.ChildElements
        Dim relID As String = TryCast(slideIDs(index), SlideId).RelationshipId


        Dim slide As SlidePart = DirectCast(part.GetPartById(relID), SlidePart)
        Dim notesSlide As NotesSlidePart = slide.NotesSlidePart
        Dim sn As NotesSlide = notesSlide.NotesSlide


        Dim textx As IEnumerable(Of A.Text) = sn.Descendants(Of A.Text)()
        Dim notesText As New StringBuilder()

        For Each text As A.Text In textx

            notesText.Append(text.Text)

        Next


        Dim paragraphText As New StringBuilder()

        Dim texts As IEnumerable(Of A.Text) = slide.Slide.Descendants(Of A.Text)()

        For Each text As A.Text In texts
            paragraphText.Append(text.Text)
        Next

        sldText = paragraphText.ToString() & notesText.ToString() 'concatenates the notes and slide text for searching

    End Using


End Function
```

## End Region

## Region "PDF Processing"

```
Public Function pdfProcesssing(ByVal strDoc As String, ByVal target As String) As Integer


    Dim oReader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(strDoc)
    Dim stringOut As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    If File.Exists(strDoc) Then


        For i = 1 To oReader.NumberOfPages

            Dim itsText As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy
            stringOut.Append(iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, i, itsText))

        Next


    End If

    Return catchallProcessing(stringOut.ToString(), target)

End Function
```

## End Region

```
End Module
```